# Query para ordenar datos alfanumericos en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

estoy tratando de ordenar los datos de una tabla, la idea es odenarlos por nombre y después por número con el siguiente query de mysql.

> SELECT objeto FROM objetos ORDER BY objeto ASC

Esta es la tabla

```
objeto
Silla 1
Silla 10
Silla 2
Buro rojo 1
Buro rojo 11
Buro rojo 2
Buro rojo 3
Escritorio 1
Escritorio 12
Escritorio 2
Escritorio 3
```

Y debería de quedar ordenada de la siguiente forma

```
objeto
Buro rojo 1
Buro rojo 2
Buro rojo 3
Buro rojo 11
Escritorio 1
Escritorio 2
Escritorio 3
Escritorio 12
Silla 1
Silla 2
Silla 10
```

Vi que algunos usan lenght para ordenar por longitud, pero el problema aquí es que la longitud puede variar, así como también el nombre, lo que se me ocurrió es tomar la primera letra y el ultimo dato para así poder ordenar, pero no sé bien como puedo hacer esto.
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me ha quedado una cosa asi, a ver si te sirve:

```
SELECT objeto 
  FROM `objeto` 
  ORDER BY 
    SUBSTR(
      objeto, 
      1, 
      (LENGTH(objeto) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1))-1))
    ,
    CAST(
      SUBSTR(
        objeto, 
        -(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1))
      )
    ) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Para facilitar su corta y pega pongo lo mismo en una linea:

```
SELECT objeto FROM `objeto` ORDER BY SUBSTR(objeto, 1, (LENGTH(objeto) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1))-1)), CAST(SUBSTR(objeto, -(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1)))) AS UNSIGNED);
```

### Explicación detallada por partes:

- **SELECT objeto**: Queremos sacar la columna `objeto` solamente
- **FROM objeto**: De la tabla `objeto`
- **ORDER BY**: Con los siguientes parametros de ordenación

Hasta aquí era lo previsible, pero ahora se complica un poco más.

Vamos a querer dos criterios de ordenación, el primero deberá ser solamente el nombre y el segundo los numeros de cada registro contenido en un único campo.  Si nos fijamos vemos que tienen un delimitador común, que es un espacio entre el nombre y el número final, aunque cuidado, porque el nombre tambien puede contener espacios.

Por lo tanto vamos a intentar dividir ese campo en dos, y para ello vamos a usar la función `SUBSTR`, que permite la extracción de partes del valor pasado.

Vamos con el primero:

- **SUBSTR**: Su sintaxis es: `SUBSTR(cadena, inicio, longitud)`, así que vamos a desgranarlos uno a uno:
- ***cadena***: En este caso hablamos de la cadena completa, es decir, `objeto`
- ***inicio***: Queremos que la subcadena empiece al principio, es decir, le asginamos el valor `1`.
- ***longitud***: Como queremos la cadena sin numeros, deberemos calcular su longitud, y para ello empleamos la función `LENGTH`, pero deberemos restarle la parte numérica del final y el espacio entre ambas partes. Por lo tanto, el cálculo queda así:

  LENGTH(objeto) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1))-1

Vamos a analizarlo más en detalle:

- **LENGTH(objeto)**: Se corresponde con la longitud total de los caracteres del campo, incluídos los números
- **LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1)**: Se corresponde con la longitud de los numeros a partir del espacio final que los separa, sin tener en cuenta los espacios de los nombres.  ***¿Y como conseguimos eso?*** Pues gracias a `SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1)` que si lo despiezamos de nuevo seria así:
- ***SUBSTRING_INDEX***: Es una función que permite extraer la parte de una cadena a partir de un delimitador que puede aparecer `n` veces. Su sintaxis es `SUBSTRING_INDEX(cadena, delimitador, número)` donde:
- ***cadena***: De nuevo la cadena completa, `objeto`.
- ***delimitador***: En este caso es un espacio, y lo ponemos así `' '`
- ***número***: Es el número de veces que debemos encontrar el delimitador. Si es positivo va de izquierda a derecha, pero en nuestro caso lo ponemos negativo para que empiece por la derecha y se pare en la primera ocurrencia donde encuentra el delimitador yendo hacia la izquierda, es decir, en nuestro caso, el numero que aparece al final de cada campo. Por eso su valor es `-1`.

Ahora ya tenemos la longitud total y al longitud de los numeros, que si las restamos nos da la longitud del campo sin los números, pero ojo, que nos queda un espacio al final por eliminar, y por eso tambien le restamos `-1` al final de esta operación.

Con esto ya hemos completado el primer criterio de ordenación.

Ahora vamos a por el segundo, que separamos con una `,` y que son los números: `CAST(SUBSTR(objeto, -(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1)))) AS UNSIGNED)`.

- **CAST ... AS UNSIGNED**:  Con esta función, cuya sintaxis es `CAST(valor AS tipodatos)` convertimos el resultado a enteros (para ello aquí el tipodatos seria UNSIGNED si no me equivoco). El contenido de `...` (*valor*) en nuestro caso es:
- **SUBSTR(objeto, -(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(objeto,' ',-1))))**: Esto lo he explicado más arriba, así que lo voy a resumir como la extracción de los números para su ordenación, pero al extraerlos quizás sean tratados como texto, y por eso forzamos su cambio de tipo con `CAST` anteriormente mencionado. La única diferencia es que a la función `SUBSTR` no le pongo el tercer parámetro de longitud, para que así la coja toda hasta el final.

Por lo tanto ya tenemos completada la consulta, que espero que cumpla con tus expectativas, o al menos te sirva como punto de partida para conseguir lo que quieres, si no es esto que acabo de explicar exactamente.

¡Si has llegado a leer hasta aquí te felicito!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias masterguru, sin lugar a duda la mejor respuesta que he recibido en todas las consultas que he hecho, me funciono a la perfección, de verdad te agradezco mucho por la explicación y el tiempo que tomaste en responderme, y claro que lo leí todo y analice todas las partes.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado, y que hayas leido hasta el final. Seguramente se podria mejorar la consulta, pero la he ido aprendiendo mientras la hacia y cuando he visto que ha funcionado la he dado por terminada y he redactado lo aprendido para la comunidad por si sirve para alguien más pues me ha parecido una pregunta muy interesante (que al principio no entendí bien, todo hay que decirlo, pues pense que te faltaba el nombre de la segunda columna, je, que no existe pues es todo en una sola). Gracias a ti tambien.

Comment: Gracias masterguru, es muy bueno que haya gente como tu que le guste aprender y enseñar :)